# how to select particular column after importing csv

Tags: excel, csv, powershell

I used import-csv cmdlet and imported csv file with many columns and row.[image: snapshot of the imported csv]

I want to choose only account number field which is not 0 and separate them "," and store it to string. How can i choose that particular field from the import-csv list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` to grab the value of just a single property, then use `Where-Object` to filter out those with value `0`:

```
$AccountNumbers = Import-Csv .\data.csv |Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Account Number' |Where-Object {$_ -ne "0"}
```

And then use the `-join` operator to produce your string:

```
$CommaSeparatedString = $AccountNumbers -join ','
```

Comment: perfect. Thanks for quick answer.